# Selective Forbidden error

Tags: php, apache, permissions, cpanel

I am experiencing a weird problem.

I have a contact form written in php, in several computers the page works without any problems,
but in two specific computers, as i send the form i get a 403 error.

even weirder is, if the form isn't filled correctly, it doesn't give me the 403.

I gave every folder and file that might be related to that page 0755 permissions, so i don't think that's the problem.

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the form do with the data that is posted? You say if some of the data isn't filled in that it does work. What data is omitted to make it work?

Comment: What is the webserver and OS ? apache and linux ? if so you need to have the right directory setup on apache to allow scripts to run. Do you have suphp enabled ? what is the error showing up at error_log of either... ?

Comment: OK, so the data posted is text, I meant if the form is filled not correctly it sends the form to the next page, but displays the errors to the user, the data doesn't get into the DB.

Its apache and Linux, the error log shows a 403 error.
The thing is, php runs perfectly on the server, the problem happens only in 2 computers, only in this part of the form, the rest of the computers i checked worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you said that it works without any problems on *some* computers I want to say that it is probably a caching issue on those problematic computers.  Try clearing your browsing history/cache and trying again.

If it still causes errors you would probably get better results if you post the HTTP headers that you receive from computers that CAN access the site and computers that CANNOT access the site so that we can compare the results.  You can use Firefox's Live HTTP Headers to capture the output pretty easily.